# Comparison of means between two groups using additional information

Tags: change-point

I would be glad if you help me with at least one of the questions.

**General question:** there are two groups, sampled from normal distributions with only two means (one for each group) and different variances for each point. Can I increase the power of test on difference between means, taking into account information about different variances? One group is sampled from $(\mathcal N(\mu_a, \sigma_1), \ldots, \mathcal N(\mu_a, \sigma_k))$, another from $(\mathcal N(\mu_b, \sigma_{k+1}), \ldots, \mathcal N(\mu_b, \sigma_n))$

**Particular situation:**

Conceptually, I have a time series and I want to find a change point.

Time series is from distribution $\mathcal N(\mu_a, \sigma_1), \mathcal N(\mu_a, \sigma_2), \ldots, \mathcal N(\mu_a, \sigma_k), \mathcal N(\mu_b, \sigma_{k+1}), \ldots, \mathcal N(\mu_b, \sigma_n)$.

Problem: I do not know the moment of switch $k$, I do not know $\mu_a$ and $\mu_b$.

How it is typically solved: t-test or any other test on means between groups, greedy search of change point. It does not take different $\sigma$ into account. Paired with BIC on number of change points, this method skips short segments in time series.

Question: I have functional dependency between $\sigma$ and $\mu$ for each coordinate $i$ in the vector, so $\sigma_i = f_i(\mu)$. Can I construct more powerful test for change point detection, using this additional information?

Current approach: use local search for change point (sliding window) and find maximum likelihood solution (greedy) for this problem. However, it is computationally expensive (I need to iterate all $\mu$ for all positions) and not suitable for long vectors.